# Sending message by FB messenger

Tags: android, facebook

Since few days sending text by intent to facebook messenger is not working, I've tried several approaches:
first:

```
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getString(R.string.messenger_text));
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
```

second (based on facebook docs):

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getString(R.string.messenger_text));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PROTOCOL_VERSION, PROTOCOL_VERSION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_ID);
```

Anyone have working example? I think this is new problem realted to last facebook messenger api update.

Comment: I think you can only send image by intent. Please check the doc here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android

Comment: Sending text in intent is no more supported. Now you should use Message Dialog

Comment: @user1483208 Same problem here.. I was trying to send a text through messenger for a whole day... It's not working.. have you got anything working?

Comment: @user1483208  Yep Got it , Thanks a lot but why would facebook do this to us???

Comment: @Dev I don't have idea. This solution is worse, because you need send a link :/

Comment: Beginning early May 2015 Messenger no longer register itself as share intent target. Until it changes, code above won't work.

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me :

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My message to send");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");

    try {
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ToastHelper.show(this, "Please Install Facebook Messenger");
    }
```

Comment: It's work but there is no confirmation or something :/

Comment: how to send for an user id

Answer (score 1):

Here is working solution with new API:

```
if (MessageDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                        .setContentTitle("TITLE")
                        .setContentDescription("Desc")
                        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://url"))
                        .build();

                messageDialog.show(linkContent);
            } else {
                showInfoDialog(getString(R.string.info_dialog_messenger_not_found));
            }
```